# ELK Kibana Watcher mail: Substring in text?

Tags: kibana

I've set up mail action on a watcher in Kibana/ELK.

In the body, I'm using `"text": "{{ctx}}"`.

However, I need to parse out a few tokens from ctx.

Is it possible to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the "token" is a section of the context then you'll be able to extract it by specifying the path to the section. For eg, ctx.payload.hits.hits.0._source.message will get you the 1st result of the message in the context.